# Using stegonography to find a secret message in a bmp image

Tags: encryption, steganography

I have been struggling with this assignment for a while now and I feel completely lost.
I have this image:
[image: Image with secret message]

There is a hidden message in it, hidden using LSD coding. I understand the concept of changing the least significant bits, (the one furthest to the right) but I can't quite figure out how to extract a message. I have looked at the image with [this](https://incoherency.co.uk/image-steganography/#unhide) tool and located some weird looking pixels at the very bottom. The problem is I don't know how to locate them and extract a message from it. I think bmp is bottom up so they should be at the top of the hex code. Anyways I would be happy if anyone could help me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

LSD steganography uses the least siginificant digit (ie, the least significant bit).  Go through the image file, ignoring the headers, just looking at the bytes forming the actual image.  From each byte extract the least significant bit.  Every eight bytes you will have 8 bits, which make a single byte of the hidden massage.  Assemble the bits into bytes, and assemble the bytes into the hidden message.